# Derivative of Euclidean motion w.r.t to parametrized curve

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, euclidean-geometry, linear-transformations

Let $F \in \operatorname{E}(n)$ be a Euclidean motion, i.e. $F = Ax + b$, where $A \in \operatorname{O}(n)$ and $b \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and let $c:I \subset \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be a curve parametrized by arc length. I want to calculate the derivative of $F \circ c$. Here's what I get by using the chain rule and the fact that $F' = A$:

$\frac{d}{dt} F(c(t)) = \frac{d}{dt} \left( Ac(t) + b \right) = \frac{d}{dt} Ac(t) + \frac{d}{dt}b = c'(t)Ac(t)$.

However, my text book says that $(F \circ c)'(t) = Ac'(t)$. Where's my error and what is the correct way to derive this function? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: In your last step, you switched the order of $A$ and $c$ when you applied the chain rule. $\frac{d}{dt} \left( A \circ c \right) = A \circ c'$.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, Nick. Yes, you're correct. I used the formula $D_{\mathbf{a}}(f \circ g) = D_{g(\mathbf{a})}f \circ D_{\mathbf{a}}g$. But besides that my confusion stems from the lack of $c(t)$ in the derivative. Is the derivative of $F(x) = Ax + b$ equal to $Ax$ or to $A$?. If the argument gets dropped that would explain the lack of $c(t)$ in the derivative...

Comment: The derivative of $F$ is just the matrix $A$. This is because in the chain rule, $D_{c(t)}F = A$ (it is always $A$ at every point). And then $D_t c = c'(t)$, which is a vector that you "plug in" to the matrix (meaning matrix multiplication).